# Formatting using IOS members

Tags: c++, iostream

I have the following code, just have a look at it

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a=56;
    cout.setf(ios::hex);

    cout<<"\nyou have entered "<<a;/*this statement must output a value in hexadecimal*/
    _getch();
    cout.unsetf(ios::hex);
    cout<<"\n modified value"<<a; /*& it should give me an answer 56*/

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

but the first commented statement is not working for me, it also prints out 56. Am I doing a mistake, or anything else?
(I am using a visual c++,compiler).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the two argument version of `setf` because the base settings of the format flags isn't a single bit, it uses a number of bits:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield );
```

The two parameter version of `setf` ensures that `basefield` bits that need to be cleared are actually cleared.

Similarly, you can't "unset" `hex` because it's not a single bit, you have to set a different base:

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::dec, std::ios_base::basefield );
```

**Most importantly: note that in the current standard, hexadecimal formatting for `ostream` only applies to integers, not floating point types. You will need to use or cast to an integer to see a hexadecimal output.**

For the avoidance of all doubt this code sample "works" as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 56;
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::hex, std::ios_base::basefield );
    std::cout << "Hex: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::dec, std::ios_base::basefield );
    std::cout << "Dec: " << a << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hex: 38
Dec: 56
```

Comment: but when i implemented your suggestion on setf(),it works,but even if ignore your suggestion about the unsetf(),it still works,that is it yields  the value i have assigned 56...?????what's going on

Comment: People don't tend to answer questions with more than one question mark in them.

Comment: i have tested it using an int too,but using setf() with one argument even then not works as stated in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
```

or just

```
cout << ios::hex;
```